# Create Mongodb query in c# with And and Or Clause

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection which is having "Tags" as Array object. Now I want to make a query in C# using builders.

I need to create a query where I will pass value in tags something like -

(T1 or T2) and (T3 or T4 or T5 or T6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `.And(` with `.AnyIn(`?:

```
IMongoCollection<Model> collection;
var builder = Builders<Model>.Filter;
var result = collection.Find(
        builder.And(
            builder.AnyIn(m => m.Tags, new [] { "T1", "T2" },
            builder.AnyIn(m => m.Tags, new[] { "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6" }
        )
    );
```